# Box outside my y axis in matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, seaborn, heatmap

I"m trying to add a descriptive box outside my y axis on my heatmap in matplotlib/seaborn.  I tried an additional subplot and hspan, but they weren't working for me.  Help please!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

col1, col2 = np.random.rand(31), np.random.rand(31)

df = pd.DataFrame({'first': col1,
                   'second': col2}, index = range(70,101))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize = (5,10))
sns.heatmap(data=df, annot=True, cmap='RdYlGn', cbar=False)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.tick_params('y', labelrotation=0)
```

Here is a picture of the box beside the y axis for reference.
[image: Example box outside my y axis]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create two subplots, put the heatmap in the right subplot and the text in the left one.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'first': np.random.rand(31),
                   'second': np.random.rand(31)}, index=range(70, 101))

sns.set()
fig, (ax0, ax) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(5, 10), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1, 3]})
sns.heatmap(data=df, annot=True, cmap='RdYlGn', cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.tick_params('y', labelrotation=0)
y_break = 21 / 31
ax0.axhspan(0, y_break, color='turquoise')
ax0.axhspan(y_break, 1, color='tomato')
ax0.axis('off')
ax0.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax0.text(0.5, y_break / 2, 'good', fontsize=24, rotation=90, ha='center', va='center')
ax0.text(0.5, (1 + y_break) / 2, 'bad', fontsize=24, rotation=90, ha='center', va='center')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: box outside the y-axis]

Comment: Johan - Fantastic job!  I was on the right track, just not clever enough to figure it out.  Thanks for your help!  BTW the bird of paradise is awesome.